# Perfomance Testing for a one class java application

Tags: java, performance, testing

I need to run perfomance testing for a simple java class which does some simple file read and write. I am new to perfomance testing and all the tools I am seeing are for web application. Which tool should I use.

My program has four methords doing same purpose and written in different logic I want to find which of the methord is more efficient

Comment: Hai @shmosel can u help me find the exising question so I can work on a solution

Comment: It's right up there ^^^

Comment: oops my bad thq